# SQL group only following rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following fields:

- **user_id** - id of a user
- **gate_id** - Id of a gate of which the user passed through
- **time** - time of which the user have passed the gate.

I wanna get a list of the gates that the users (user_id, gate_id) have passed ordered by time.
buy sometimes a user passes through a gate multiple times one right after the other.
I wanna ignore these cases.

for example if we have:

| user_id | gate_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 13 |

it will ignore only the following duplicated and return:

| user_id | gate_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 13 |

How can i do such thing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LAG` window function to find the previous `gate_id` per `user_id` ordered by your `time` column, and then filter out the undesired ones:

```sql
SELECT user_id, gate_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    gate_id, 
    lag(gate_id) OVER (
      PARTITION BY user_id 
      ORDER BY time
    ) AS previous_gate_id
  FROM t
) t
WHERE previous_gate_id IS NULL OR previous_gate_id <> gate_id
```